# How to paste value into another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a function that will be used for quarterly reporting for projects.

I have to update a template (including changing the quarterly dates) but there are over 100 projects (hence files), so it would be troublesome to change them one by one.

I am trying to create a macro that when you enter the date in e.g. cell A1 of the master template, all of the project template dates will update, and the files will autosave.

All of these files are in the same folder. The files open up when I change cell A1, they save all at the same time, but nothing changes in the folders, except in the master template.

I've tried many methods, they either return errors or continue to be blank.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
           With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
               'Assigns the value to cellValue
                Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                ActiveWorkbook.Save
            End With
            xFileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: oh i removed the worksheet change part when i was testing it so it wouldnt have to keep changing the cell to run the macro, i added it back in here to cause i wanted to show the full code but i missed out the end if! thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Paste:=xlPasteFormats` pastes only the format. So, the cell will be blank...

Try `xlPasteValues` instead.

Comment: It returns a run time error '1004' - application or object defined error. Am i referencing the newly opened file wrongly?

Comment: Could you accept one of the answers please if they've helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI you don't need to use `Copy`, you can set values directly, so

```
    With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
        'Assigns the value to cellValue
         Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
         ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
         ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End With
```

Would become:

```
    With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
        'Assigns the value to cellValue
         ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = _
         Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
         ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End With
```

It's a bit quicker and can prevent errors if users are playing around with the computer while macros are running!

Answer (score 0):

This is a general example how to copy/paste from one range to another. It s better to avoid `ActiveWorkbook`.

```
Sub Copy_Paste()
    
    With ThisWorkbook
    
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy
    
        .Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
    End With
  
End Sub
```